# iPhone Browser stops downloading resources to the HTML5 Cache when user navigates during the process

Tags: javascript, caching, html, mobile-safari

I'm working on a project using the HTML5 application cache to support an offline version of my application. When the user visits the application the first time, the browser automatically downloads all the files in the cache manifest file and saves them in the cache for offline use.

In Chrome, when the user navigates to a different URL (still within my application, which also references the cache manifest file), it will continue to download the files into the cache.

However, on iOS (I've tried iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch), if you navigate during the downloading progress, it seems to halt the process and subsequent pages do not download any files at all. In fact, the only way I can get it to restart the process of downloading files into the cache, I have to go into the Mobile Safari settings and clear the cache.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does the user actually have to wait on the same page until all the resources are cached (otherwise the cache is broken). It seems like there is maybe a bug in the implementation, but maybe someone has some experience with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can post the content of your cache manifest? The first things I'd check are that (a) the relevant pages are listed in there, (b) the pages you navigate to have `manifest` attributes pointing to the cache file and (c) that you have an HTML5 doctype for each page.

You could try forcing a cache update programmatically too:

[Safari Client-Side Storage and Offline Applications Programming Guide: Updating the Cache](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007256-CH7-SW5)